# React-Native fetch Problem, please give me wisdom

Tags: javascript, react-native

[React-Native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDe9l.png)

[NodeJS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgzwq.png)

## fetch Problem

i'm trying to develop using React-Native and NodeJs but problem occur.
problem is Network Interaction === fetch

## i'm fix trying

1) cors option
2) add my private address

i don't know no more
if you fix the problem, have the experience give me wisdom!!!! please

Comment: Can you share your network code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = express()
const cors=require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   res.send()
})
```

This should allow the requests to  be made.